# CollectionView Cell is really small

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I've CollectionView in my project, I added some buttons and labels inside CollectionViewCell and did all the auto-layout, but anytime I run my project the CollectionViewCell is smaller than it is planned or appeared on my xcode storyboard, any solutions ?

```swift
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "mainCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MainCollectionViewCell
        cell.config(data: array1[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
```

```
class MainCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var postAuthor: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var postChannel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var postDate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var votesNumber: UILabel!
    
    
    func config(data:PostModel){
        self.profileImage.image = data.authorPhoto
        self.postAuthor.text = data.authorName
        self.postChannel.text = data.channelPosted
        self.postDate.text = data.date
        self.votesNumber.text = String(data.votesCount)
    }
    
}
```

screenshots for better understanding

[image: storyboard]

[image: after I run the project]

Comment: Please share your cell class.

Comment: Try setting the cell size using sizeForItemAt method (don’t forget to conform to UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout first). Or you can set the estimatedSize property of the layout.